# How to use Windows Media Foundation with UWP without a topology

Tags: uwp, ms-media-foundation

I have been reading the Polinger book "Developing Microsoft Media Foundation Applications" in order to understand the Microsoft sample MixedRemoteViewCompositor for the Hololens.  A key concept of the text is that Media Foundation components are COM objects that are connected into a graph structure called a Topology.  However, the sample code is for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) and the word "topology" does not exist anywhere in the code.  The call to create a topology does not exist in the code.

So my question is whether UWP applications use a topology in Media Foundation and if not how does one connect the Media Foundation COM components together to form a processing pipeline?  The sample code has sources and sinks but I cannot tell how they connect.

Scott

Comment: Media Foundation has two architecture: `Topology` and `Reader/Writer` - `Topology` is based on COM technology - it allows create COM media object and inject into the `Topology` processing pipeline.  `Reader/Writer` hides pipeline. UWP is developed for wide type platforms and has high demand for using the same on the different platform - as a result, UWP limits access for low level element of OS - COM is low level elements. on UWP `Reader/Writer` is only architecture for MF - it allows configure media file/stream readers, media file/stream writers, but it doe not allow use topology.

Comment: So is it possible to use Media Foundation Transforms (MFT) with the UWP architecture?

Comment: Yes. If you want add your's component with IMFTransform interface - then you must use component with IMFSourceReaderEx interface - it has method AddTransformForStream - Adds a transform, such as an audio or video effect, to a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`So my question is whether UWP applications use a topology in Media Foundation` No.

Firstly, `IMFTopologyNode` interface is not allowed in UWP.

Secondly, `IMFTopology` interface which contains `IMFTopologyNode`, is not allowed in UWP.

Thirdly, `IMFMediaSession` interface which creates media pipeline by `IMFTopology`, is not allowed in UWP,

Fourthly, `MFCreateMediaSession` - "C" function which creates `IMFMediaSession`, is not allowed in UWP.

`not how does one connect the Media Foundation COM components together to form a processing pipeline?` - it is done behind of MF components with [IMFSourceReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374655(v=vs.85).aspx) and [IMFSinkWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374642(v=vs.85).aspx) - developer **CANNOT** have direct access to those processing pipelines.

`So is it possible to use Media Foundation Transforms (MFT) with the UWP architecture?` Yes.
If you want add your's component with `IMFTransform` interface - then you must use component with [IMFSourceReaderEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448062(v=vs.85).aspx) interface - it has method [AddTransformForStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448063(v=vs.85).aspx) - `Adds a transform, such as an audio or video effect, to a stream.`

About `How create Source Reader` you can read there - [Source Reader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940436(v=vs.85).aspx)